# Receiving errorCode 1004 with /token API endpoint

Tags: oauth, smartsheet-api

**Do oauth token grants require a paid account?** I attempted the following with both a free and trial account.

Sending /token POST [as documented](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#oauth-flow) results in:

```
{
   "errorCode": 1004,
   "message": "You are not authorized to perform this action.",
   "refId": "cd9hgzwmdduh"
}
```

I use these parameters:

```
grant_type: authorization_code
code: <acquired from step 1. in oauth flow>
hash: <see below>
```

I acquired the `hash` parameter with the following commandline operation:

```
export app_secret=<acquired from developer app profile.>
export code=<code acquired from step 1 in oauth flow.>
echo -n "$app_secret$code" | openssl dgst -sha256
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These were my errors that I corrected before successfully achieving [Get Access Token](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#get-access-token) endpoint:

1. When creating the SHA256 hash I forgot to concatenate `|` in between the `app_secret` and the `code`.  The correct sha256 hash to send should be:

   `echo -n "$app_secret|$code" | openssl dgst -sha256`
2. Header should be:

   `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
3. Instead of sending as url query parameters, I should send as x-www-form-urlencoded parameters.

Here is a full text of the HTML protocol:

```
POST /2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.smartsheet.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=<client_id>&code=<code from step 1 of oauth flow>&hash=<see above>
```

```